# Conditional statement inside where clause to account for null values

Tags: sql

I have a table shaped like so:

```
ID  | Value  | Value_Comp
101 |  3     |   2
102 |  2     |   4 
103 |  7     |   NULL
104 |  1     |   4
```

I want to select all IDs where Value < Value_Comp, but if there's a NULL value, then select the data if value > 5

So in this scenario, IDs `102, 103, and 104` would be selected.

Edit: I have a ton of other where conditions. Is there an easy way to write this so I don't have to repeat all of them twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from t
where (value_comp is null and value > 5)
    or value < value_comp;
```

You can put the two condition in brackets and then add other conditions in the where clause:

```
select *
from t
where ((value_comp is null and value > 5) or value < value_comp)
     and <condition 1> and <condition 2> . . .;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to nest this with a bunch of other where conditions so I don't repeat everything twice?

Comment: @NBC - Updated the answer. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE Value < Value_Comp OR (Value_Comp IS NULL AND Value > 5)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to nest this with a bunch of other where conditions so I don't repeat everything twice?